# Log in to Django site through Facebook

Tags: python, django, facebook

I am using Django.

I used `facebook-connect` to put a Facebook login button on my page. This functionality works very well. Any user can click on the button and can log in to Facebook directly. I can also store Facebook user information, such as name and email address, in my site database.

But I would like users to be able to click on the Facebook login button and also log in to my site too. At the moment they can log in only to Facebook. How can I use the Facebook login button to also authenticate the user on my site?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the widely used [django-facebook](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-facebook) app.

Comment: i already visit this link, but i am not able to authenticate user on my site

Answer (score 0):

You can look to django docs:

[other authentication sources](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#other-authentication-sources)

And write a custom backend:

```
class MyBackend(object):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        # Check the fb user is logged in, create User if needed and return a User by fbid.
```